# Creating a MySQL update statement in Google Sheet

Tags: mysql, google-sheets

I do some text operations in Google Sheet.

I then update a MySQL db with the result.

Im trying to create a formula to 'build' the Update statement, the problem is that the text have special characters that breaks the statement. And I cant forsee what special characters there will be.

Its my guess this problem is not new in anyway, is there a quick and dirty solution or would I have to manyally check every äUpdate' statement?

I have tried cleaning the 'Update' statement manually, but its a never endig story.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You need to terminate special characters when they are passed to MySQL.  A short example of said characters are :

- Single Quote '
- Forward Slash /

And what you need to do is terminate them when passing them to MySQL, so if the string has a forward slash you need to send MySQL a pair of them // .  So use a Replace command in your statement to convert / into //, or what ever character in which you are having an issue.

And .. this is just a trick I like to use, and it might not be suggested as MAYBE you have a single quote that you NEED to be a single quote, but you COULD Replace all  single quote  characters with this ' <-- character.  And if the string is like bob's cat, turn it into bob`s cat and very few people will even know you did anything, and now you don't have to worry about terminating that character anymore.

Replace (string, "/", "//" )    (Terminate )

or

Replace (string, "/", "" )    (Remove)

Answer (score 0):

In your mysql, your can change the character-set to the same you are using in your google sheets (UTF-8 in my case, do not know which you use).

[all char-set and how to change](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403914/default-mysql-character-set-and-collation#:%7E:text=utf8%20COLLATE%20utf8_general_ci%3B-,Run%20the%20following%20command%20to%20change%20the%20character%20set%20and,collation%20with%20your%20desired%20values.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).